# Projection Theorem for closed convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, projection

Consider the following statement:

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a closed convex set. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ the projection of $x$ on $C$, denoted by $\text{Proj}_{C}(x)$, is defined as follows

$$
\text{Proj}_{C}(x) = \text{argmin}_{y \in C} ||x-y||_{2}^{2}.
$$
Then it can be shown that $\text{Proj}_{C}(x)$ is unique for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.  Why the set $C$ must be closed or convex for the uniqueness?

Comment: As it turns out, in $\Bbb{R}^n$, being closed and convex is equivalent to the projection being unique. However, it's an open problem (known as the Chebyshev conjecture) if this holds in infinite dimensions. No one knows if there's a set, in infinite dimensions for which the projection is unique, but the set is not convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not closed, the projection might not exist. Consider e.g. $C = (0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x = 2$.

If it's not convex the projection might not be unique. For this case consider e.g. $C = \{0\} \cup \{2\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $x = 1$. All elements in $C$ minimize the distance to $x$.